# How to get back roles in apex?

Tags: oracle-apex

My problem is: Apex suggested me to change the admin passoword and i've changed the password in apex 4.1 application express. But after logout from my workspace and trying to login back apex has rejected my credetencials. And I don't why? Because the browser account saves my login data and pass automatically. Now I'm in bad situation. I've tried to reset password but we don't know the email which has been specified in apex for reseting password. Any suggestitions??

Comment: One of our programmers has reset the admin password via apxxepwd.sql code. And we got access to the apex web interface but we dont have access to app. All admin options has been disappeared from interface!

Comment: Login to the APEX instance admin (INTERNAL workspace) and you will be able to reset the password for any account.